# Scratchoff effect using texture brush to remove a cover image and tell when most is gone

Tags: c#

What Ive done is put an image in picturebox1 background image then drawn a cover image over top of the image.  With picturebox1 mouse move if the mouse is down it erases parts of the cover to reveal the bottom image basically like a scratch off ticket.  I cant figure out how to judge if  MOST of the cover image is erased.  This is what I have so far

```
    bmp1 = new Bitmap(coverimage);
    tb = new TextureBrush(pictureBox1.BackgroundImage);


private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{

    base.OnPaint(e);

    e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp1, 0, 0, 400, 325);
}
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        if (!_LastPoint.IsEmpty)
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
            using (Pen p = new Pen(tb, 50))
            {

                p.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                p.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                g.DrawLine(p, _LastPoint, e.Location);

                if (!g.Equals (bmp1))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("done");
                }
            }
        }

        _LastPoint = e.Location;
       pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

the !g.Equals (bmp1) notifies me when the image is altered but I cant find a way to make it only notify me if the image changes a drastic amount.  Is there anyway to judge this?

update:::

```
 static int flags = 0;
 public static void ImageCompareString(Bitmap firstImage, Bitmap secondImage)
 {
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
          firstImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
          String firstBitmap = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
          ms.Position = 0;
          secondImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
          String secondBitmap = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

   if (firstBitmap.Equals(secondBitmap))
              {
                  flags = flags + 1;
              }
             else
              {

              }
```

Some how I got the above to work for what I needed by counting the flags and when they were >= 50 allowing the next step and clearing the mask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a 'mask' image to find out the percentage uncovered by the user:

To do so, create an image with a white background on which you'll also draw these lines but with a black pen, then from this hidden image you can easily find the percentage uncovered by counting the number of pixels that aren't white using [Bitmap.GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function.

Be careful when comparing colors with [Color.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e03x8ct2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (taken from Remarks section) :
*To compare colors based solely on their ARGB values, you should use the ToArgb method. This is because the Equals and Equality members determine equivalency using more than just the ARGB value of the colors.*

Comment: Except don't use `GetPixel` since it is *really* slow.  Instead try `LockBits`.

Comment: I like the idea behind your answer, and it would probably work better for anyone that planned to do this for a published application but I'm doing this for fun and I don't want to add another mask to the application plus I got the revised version of my question to work with what I need.  However I'm choosing your answer in-case anyone runs across this looking for something like this so they can go the route you described as I'm sure its more stable.  Thank you